# Is there any tenant level audit trail API for OneDrive For Business?

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business, auditing

I'm looking for an API that provides tenant level audit trail for events performed by the tenant users.
The APIs I have gone through are all per user based events. So let's say I have 10 users and all of them are active, I want audit trail for events performed by them in order i.e, if user 1 shares something and user 2 uploads a file, then I'd like to get these events in order.

I have tried the Management Events API for Office 365, but the ETA for events is upto 24 hours which is too slow.